# DLL will not build for only one project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, build

I am trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2013. There are no errors with the project but it will not build. There are several other projects in the solution and they are all building and push the DLL to the bin/Debug location just fine. This particular project suddenly does not. Any ideas? I have set Copy Local to true and verified the path for which it is supposed to push the DLL and it is bin\Debug.

Comment: Build > Configuration Manager > click the Build checkbox for the project.

Comment: Set MS Build options to Verbose and see the reason nothing happens. What happens if you right click the project in Solution Explorer and select Rebuild All?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the following:

1. Open the Configuration Manager for the solution, verify that "Build" is checked off for the configuration currently being used.
2. BuildAction property is set to "Compile" for the source code file(s) in the project (look in the properties window when you have the source file selected in the Solution Explorer)

Comment: The build option was already checked for the project and the compile option is selected for the source code. Any other ideas? Like I said it is only for this project in the solution. I have tried uninstalling Visual Studio and nothing up to this point has worked.